# Laravel 4 raw query

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I've declared an public function in my controller:

```
public function deaths()
{
    $getdeaths = DB::statement('SELECT * FROM player_deaths ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 10');
    return View::make('main.latestdeaths')->with('getdeaths', $getdeaths);
}
```

And then I tried to retrieve the data:

```
<td>{{ $getdeaths->player_id }}</td>
```

But it doesn't work. Getting an `Trying to get property of non-object` error. Is it possible to retrieve it or?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
public function deaths()
{
    $getdeaths = DB::select( DB::raw('SELECT * FROM player_deaths ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 10') );
    return View::make('main.latestdeaths')->with('getdeaths', $getdeaths);
}
```

Comment: still getting the same error, that `{{ $getdeaths->player_id }}` is highlighted.

Comment: looks like your query is returning no rows... try to dd($getdeaths) in your deaths() method.

Comment: Its an array of objects, so you need to make a foreach loop to iterate trough everey $getdeath row

Comment: @JensMombaerts weird, I've tried that before and it didn't work. Now it works. Thanks ;P